# Excel: search for a value in a table. then display the leftmost cell on the row of where value is found. Same for upmost cell in its column

Tags: excel

I'm searching for the maximum in a table, using MAX([table_range]). Then I would like to display the value of the leftmost table cell on the row where the maximum is found. Same for the upmost cell value on the column where the maximum is found.

For example, in the table below, where the maximum is 40 (at G73), I would like to display G71(5) and E73(2).

### **___________**|  E  | F | G | H |

### seventy-one_  |__| 4 | 5 | 6 |

### seventy-two_  | 1 |10|20|30|

### seventy-three| 2 |20|40|20|

### seventy-four_| 3 |10|30|20|

Comment: Is the matrix always 3x3?

Comment: in this case it's 4x4 but it can be any size axb

Answer (score 0):

This is an array formula so enter it by holding down **ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces **{...}** around the formula in the formula bar.

For the leftmost row entry:

```
=INDEX(table_range,SUM(IF(table_range = MAX(table_range),ROW(table_range)-MIN(ROW(table_range))+1)),1)
```

For the top of the column entry:

```
=INDEX(table_range,1,SUM(IF(table_range = MAX(table_range),COLUMN(table_range)-MIN(COLUMN(table_range))+1)))
```

**EDIT:** To clarify, table_range refers to the entire table, including the first column.
Also, if there are duplicates of the highest value, the formula will not work.  You will have to decide on a rule to differentiate which value to match.